# The specified table does not exist

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I'm try to use fluent nhibernate but my nunit test it failing with a The error

```
CookBook.Tests.FluentCategoryTests.CanCorrectlyMapCategory:
System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException : The specified table does not exist. [ Category ]
```

this is my Category object

```
public class Category
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and here is the test

```
[TestFixture]
class FluentCategoryTests
{

    private ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;
    private RecipeConfiguration configuration = new RecipeConfiguration();
    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public void TestSetup()
    {
        var cfg = new RecipeConfiguration();
        _sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(MsSqlCeConfiguration.Standard.ShowSql().ConnectionString("Data Source=CookBook.sdf"))
            .Mappings(m => m.AutoMappings.Add(AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Category>(cfg)))
            .BuildSessionFactory();
    }
    [Test]
    public void CanCorrectlyMapCategory()
    {
        using (ISession session = _sessionFactory.OpenSession())
        {
            new PersistenceSpecification<Category>(session)
            .CheckProperty(c => c.Id, 1)
            .CheckProperty(c => c.Name, "Dessert")
            .VerifyTheMappings();
        }
    }
}
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: does CookBook.sdf already exist or is it created for each test? if created you are missing `new SchemaExport(cfg).Execute(false, true, false)` which creates the schema in the database

Comment: thanks, I'll check that when I get home.

Comment: just to clarify where to put it: `.Mappings(...).ExposeConfiguration(config => SchemaExport(config).Execute(false, true, false))`

Comment: thanks i was wondering about that.

Comment: What namespace is SchemaExport in?  i'm getting the error The type or namespace name 'SchemaExport' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to answer the question in your comment:

```
using NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl;

...

    var cfg = new RecipeConfiguration();
    _sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
        .Database(MsSqlCeConfiguration.Standard.ShowSql().ConnectionString("Data Source=CookBook.sdf"))
        .Mappings(m => m.AutoMappings.Add(AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Category>(cfg)))
        .ExposeConfiguration(config => new SchemaExport(config).Execute(false, true, false))
        .BuildSessionFactory();
```